# BIML error: Could not resolve reference to OdbcSource12.SQLCommand in property 'Property'. '' is invalid

Tags: ssis, properties, odbc, biml

I have to generate an SSIS package using BIML script and I have de error described in the title, hoping that someone could help me. I have to use an ODBC source connection because the source data is a AS400 database.
Most likely, I have to add somewhere a custom property, but I don't know were. I designed a package manually and works fine, my problem is that I have to generate the package using BIML.

Thank you

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Projects>
    <PackageProject Name="BCA.Queen.SSIS.ETL">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="ETLDateTimedPath" DataType="String" IsRequired="true" IsSensitive="false"></Parameter>
        <Parameter Name="ConnString_XXXXX" DataType="String" IsRequired="true" IsSensitive="false"></Parameter>
        <Parameter Name="ExtractStart" DataType="String" IsRequired="true" IsSensitive="false"></Parameter>
        <Parameter Name="ExtractEnd" DataType="String" IsRequired="true" IsSensitive="false"></Parameter>
      </Parameters>
      <Packages>
        <Package PackageName="Aici_Extract mnp_Customers" />
      </Packages>
    </PackageProject>
  </Projects>
  <Connections>
    <FlatFileConnection Name="FlatFileDestinationmnp_Customers" DelayValidation="true" FilePath="D:\ETL\QueenETL\Dan\XXXXX\Customers.dat" FileFormat="FlatFileDestinationmnp_Customers">
      <Annotations>
        <Annotation Tag="Varigence.Biml.SsisImporter.ImportedFromPackage">_Extract mnp_Customers</Annotation>
      </Annotations>
    </FlatFileConnection>
    <OdbcConnection Name="OdbcSource1" DelayValidation="true" ConnectionString="DSN=XXXXX_UAT32;provider=ODBC;">
      <Expressions>
        <Expression PropertyName="ConnectionString">@[User::ConnectionString_XXXXX]</Expression>
      </Expressions>
    </OdbcConnection>
  </Connections>
  <FileFormats>
    <FlatFileFormat Name="FlatFileDestinationmnp_Customers" CodePage="1252" TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_" RowDelimiter="CRLF">
      <Annotations>
        <Annotation Tag="Varigence.Biml.SsisImporter.ImportedFromPackage">_Extract mnp_Customers</Annotation>
      </Annotations>
      <Columns>
        <Column Name="UniqueKey" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="AccNo" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="ShortName" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="OptionsExist" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="CustName" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Address1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Address2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Address3" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Address4" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="PostCode" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Contact1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Contact2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Contact3" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Telephone1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Telephone2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Telephone3" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Fax1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Fax2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Fax3" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Email1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Email2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Email3" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="WebAddress" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Cat1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Cat2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Cat3" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="AccStatus" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="HaulageAcc" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="WarehouseAcc" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="WorkshopAcc" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="SpareAcc1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="SpareAcc2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="SpareAcc3" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Active" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Value1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Value2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Str1" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Str2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Options2" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Options3" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Options4" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Options5" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Options6" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="WebID" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="ExchangeID" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="WebVisibility" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="CreatedBy" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="CreatedDate" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Email4" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Latitude" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Longitude" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="CoordsVerified" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Exported" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="CountryCode" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="|¬|" MaximumWidth="255" />
        <Column Name="Business" Length="255" DataType="AnsiString" Delimiter="CRLF" MaximumWidth="255" />
      </Columns>
    </FlatFileFormat>
  </FileFormats>
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="Aici_Extract mnp_Customers" ConstraintMode="Linear" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" DelayValidation="true">
      <Variables>
        <Variable Name="DestinationETLPath" DataType="String" Namespace="User" EvaluateAsExpression="true">@[$Project::ETLDateTimedPath]+"XXXXX" + "\\" + "Customers"+".dat"</Variable>
        <Variable Name="ConnectionString_XXXXX" DataType="String" Namespace="User" EvaluateAsExpression="true">@[$Project::ConnString_XXXXX]</Variable>
        <Variable Name="varSelCustomers" DataType="String" Namespace="User" EvaluateAsExpression="true">
                "SELECT '" + @[$Project::ExtractStart] + "' AS Col"
            </Variable>
      </Variables>
      <Tasks>
        <Dataflow Name="DataFlow_Customers" DelayValidation="true">
          <Expressions>
            <Expression ExternalProperty="[OdbcSource12].[SqlCommand]" PropertyName="[OdbcSource12].[SqlCommand]">@[User::varSelCustomers]</Expression>
          </Expressions>
          <Transformations>
            <CustomComponent ComponentTypeName="Common Properties" Name="[OdbcSource12].[SqlCommand]" ValidateExternalMetadata="false">
              <CustomProperties>
                <CustomProperty Name="[OdbcSource12].[SqlCommand]" DataType="String"></CustomProperty>
              </CustomProperties>
            </CustomComponent>
            <OdbcSource Name="OdbcSource12" Connection="OdbcSource1" ValidateExternalMetadata="false">
              <DirectInput>
                            SELECT TOP 100 cst.UniqueKey FROM DBA.UFD01_Customers cst ORDER BY cst.UniqueKey
                        </DirectInput>
            </OdbcSource>
            <FlatFileDestination Name="FlatFileDest_Customers" ConnectionName="FlatFileDestinationmnp_Customers" Overwrite="true" ValidateExternalMetadata="false"></FlatFileDestination>
          </Transformations>
        </Dataflow>
      </Tasks>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: Could it be that your driver is 32 bit vs 64 bit? Also, the `ConnectionString` for OdbcSource1 looks awfully bare but maybe it's all embedded in the DSN.

Comment: Oh and the CustomComponent tag near the end looks questionable. If it's supposed to do something, I'd expect there to be `<CustomProperty Name="[OdbcSource12].[SqlCommand]" DataType="String"></CustomProperty>
 ` something in the tag there. You might try striking that entire CustomProperty tag and see if that works. That or try copying your existing query in there `String">SELECT TOP 100...</CustomProperty>`

Comment: The connection string is ok. I just replaced the real name with XXXXX. Like I said, the package made manually works fine with the same odbc connection string...

Comment: Based on Varigence.Biml.SsisImporter.ImportedFromPackage I presume you reverse engineered the package to Biml? The importer doesn't always catch all the cases - you might need to contact support@varigence.com and send them the package to see if they can spot where it's going askew. You can also open a ticket on their repository https://github.com/varigence/BimlPit/